Is the long, blue WindowsDebugLauncher.exe message that prints when I run C/C++ code in VS Code an error?
When I run my C program on VS Code through cpptools (the Microsoft C++ extension for VS Code), I always get this long, blue-colored message in the terminal. Sometimes the code runs and sometimes it doesn't run. It looks like an error message(?)- especially the part that says "stderror". I tried to uninstall vs code and then reinstall it but it didn't help. Is this an error message? If so, how can I fix the problem?
This is the message:
'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.20.5-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-2hzunawp.5jd' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-4c1l0eot.hlz' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-f1z5ijur.qi1' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-0dxp5msa.4og' '--dbgExe=C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
Here's what it looks like on my screen:

A similar thing happens when I try to run C++ code using cpptools.

To state the obvious, that looks like a command-line rather than an error message. Can you run that command-line manually on a command-line? Does it give you another message? (I realise that the message might not be insightful because it won't be run under Visual Studio Code, but then again it might be.) I notice also that a Dekshith asked the same question a year ago but there was no resolution.

@SmellyCat lots of people new to VS Code + C/C++ think this is an error for some reason. it's a pretty common misconception on r/vscode as well. I tried looking for a dup target on SO, couldn't find one, and then lost motivation to deal with this. I've caved and answered it now.

It's not an error. That's the command that the cpptools extension uses to start debugging when you tell it to start debugging. The part that says "--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-f1z5ijur.qi1" is specifying a file for the standard error stream when debugging.
The ^C (ctrl-c / interrupt key) you see in between them is an automatic interrupt key inserted by VS Code that I explain to some depth in my answer to VS Code 1.88 inserts ^C before running a debug configuration again. Why?.
Your code running sometimes and sometimes not is probably unrelated to this. Maybe you have compilation / link / runtime errors.
