Are these things that appear in vscode terminal okay? (when compiling c++)
I followed vscode's documentation to install the GCC compiler and confirgure it on vscode. When I run it there are some things which I think are anomalies.
When running, these 2 terminals are opened (image below)

g++.exe runs in the terminal and says "Build finished Successfully", but the second terminal is what has the weird stuff (image below)

What is this "^C" symbol? And what are the blue paths?
I tried checking the configuration JSON files, but couldn't find anything helpful.

The configuration that you selected should be saved in your tasks.json file, so it might help if you included that file in your question. I'm just guessing but maybe you have multiple configurations saved with none of the selected as the default.

I was running this file from my desktop (without a folder) and vscode only creates tasks.json when you have a folder, which contains the c++ file, opened.

Not really sure what you mean. When I try to 'run' a C++ file without having a folder open I just get an error message. Anyway I suggest you do try to run VSCode with a folder open, it is the normal way of using VSCode.

Appreciate your concern. In the vscode primary sidebar, there is the option of opening a folder. I created this file and saved it on my desktop without it being in a folder. For vscode to create tasks.json, launch.json, and settings.json the c++ file should be in a folder. Anyway, thanks for your advice @john

In any case, it is not "GCC" that is "running the code strangely". It is whatever plugin you installed (maybe one installed by defatult) to compile and run a single C++ file that generates that command line to launch (no, not compiling) your program. I can't say much about the Ctrl-C.

The last time I've checked the documentation, a clean VSCode installation didn't support C++. You had to install an extension. The behavior depends on the extension.

@MohamadKhalil These details about how you are running VSCode, and whether you do or do not have a folder open are important, and so should be in the question not in the comments.

I installed the C/C++ extension for VS code as mentioned in the documentation (link in post) and about the GCC, I know it is not the problem because compiling and running the file from CMD works perfectly using g++. The problem lies in vscode and how it handles things.

"The problem lies in vscode and how it handles things." What problem? You didn't mention a problem in the question. "I installed the C/C++ extension for VS code as mentioned in the documentation (link in post)" You should edit your question and add these details as text to your question, not behind external links.

Perhaps, I need to edit the question as it is not elaborated well. Anyway, I appreciate all the advice on modifying the question. @jabaa

Regarding the blue paths, it's how you start a program in a terminal with some command line arguments. The program is WindowsDebugLauncher.exe. The other path is an argument for --dbgExe. It has nothing to do with programming or VSCode. It's how terminals in Windows work.

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78531381/11107541. cc @john for your reference

Pressing Ctrl + C (shown as ^C in the terminal) sends a signal to terminate the currently running process. However, this is just the tip of the iceberg for what this command can do and how it works under the hood. To dive deeper, you can explore more details online about how Ctrl + C interacts with signals and process management in different operating systems.
The blue path is VS Code color-coding of specific types of messages like compiling code

Can you exlpain the ctrl + c part more? What exactly do you mean "if they didn't finish" ?

Well this is in PowerShell and not cmd, and PowerShell is very close to UNIX based terminals, you are right that this won't work on Windows terminal, but many UNIX based commands work on PowerShell
