Regarding the configuration issues when running C++ in VSCode
When running C++ in VSCode using the internal terminal, there are often many command-line arguments that get mixed with the output. How can I hide these arguments and display only the output?
enter image description here
When I use full-screen mode, everything displays correctly, but when using a windowed mode, this issue occurs. The format in the terminal also changes when resizing the window.
enter image description here
Is there any configuration that can solve this problem? (I want the program's output to display in the internal terminal, not an external terminal.) Thank you.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78531381/11107541
